# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: jquery, html, post

I don't understand where i am wrong. Please let me know the problem's solution.

```js
  function AddData(id, url, data) {
    $.post(url, data, function(result) {
      $("#res" + id).html(result);
    });
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="AddData('1','http://api.techsoul.in/movies/techsoul-update-movies.php','{ token:'',fun:'addmovie',category:'hollywood-movies-2016',poster:'',rate:'',year:'',quality:'',name:'Blowtorch 2016 ',detail:'',genre:'',link:'http://onlinemoviewatchs.tv/blowtorch-2016-full-movie-online-free/',src:'http://195.154.173.143/ykgioneek62birmpnhwgr6z3hzybauw6c4jkyc7osy5pwsygrk4q6dvgw4sa/v.mp4',playersrc:'http://putload.tv/embed-jzq59gyswkpc.html',status:'1' }');">GET RESULT</button>
<p id="res1"></p>
```

Comment: `'{ token: '',` You're wrapping the object in single quotes and using unescaped single quotes inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onclick to:

```
AddData('1','http://api.techsoul.in/movies/techsoul-update-movies.php','{ token:\'\',fun:\'addmovie\',category:\'hollywood-movies-2016\',poster:\'\',rate:\'\',year:\'\',quality:\'\',name:\'Blowtorch 2016 \',detail:\'\',genre:\'\',link:\'http://onlinemoviewatchs.tv/blowtorch-2016-full-movie-online-free/\',src:\'http://195.154.173.143/ykgioneek62birmpnhwgr6z3hzybauw6c4jkyc7osy5pwsygrk4q6dvgw4sa/v.mp4\',playersrc:\'http://putload.tv/embed-jzq59gyswkpc.html\',status:\'1\' }');
```